# PHP Sessions broken in default Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: session, php7

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server with PHP 7.4.3 (Apache 2.4.41 + mod_php) running, everything should be at its default AFAIK. But PHP sessions do not appear to be working. When running the following code, every refresh of the webpage leads to the same output (instead of incrementing) and to a new session file in `/var/lib/php/sessions`:

```
?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] += 1;
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
```

I checked it with different browsers (to exclude the possibility of my browser refusing the session cookie) and operating systems, the problem is consistent. I ran the same code on an old CentOS with PHP 5.3 - no problem there. The counter increments after every browser refresh, irrespective of browser, and the session gets updated with every request instead of being recreated. I have no clue why this problem would occur.

The rights for `/var/lib/php/sessions` on the Ubuntu machine are 1733.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was stupid. A while ago I had created an Apache VHost on that server and removed cookies for that VHost via `Header unset Set-Cookie`. Unfortunately this was the default VHost and I did my PHP session tests with just the IP address of the server (I don't have a domain yet). I found out via  my browser's developer tools - the PHPSESSID cookie was never sent in the HTTP response header and then I remembered my odd choice in the default VHost.